# QML - How to change TextField font size

Tags: qml, textfield, font-size

How can I set the font size of a TextField element in QML?  wanna change size of the `placeholderText` and also for the text which the user enters.

I tried with a lot of ways without luck!

```
TextField {
    id: name_TextField; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter;
    Layout.preferredWidth: parentCLayer.width * 0.90; Layout.preferredHeight: 50
    style: TextFieldStyle {
        font.pixelSize: 20  // This doesn't seem to work either
    }
    placeholderText: qsTr("Your name here")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `style` property to customize your `TextField`. For example:

```js
TextField {
    style: TextFieldStyle {
        font.pixelSize: 14
    }
}
```

I tried it and it works like a charm

Comment: Weird, can you please tell me what are the `import` statements in your QML file?

Comment: Sure, 
`import QtQuick.Controls 1.2`

`import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2`

I use Qt 5.3.1

Comment: This does work, although the IDE flags the `font` reference with the error: "font" does not have members. (M17)

Answer (score 2):

## Using the `font` member of TextField

The `TextField` type itself has a member `font` which contains an instance of the [QML basic type `font`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-font.html). It's sufficient to change the values of the inner-members of the `font` member of `TextField` to make the changes you want to see. Note that the color is provided by the TextField itself, not the font type.

```
TextField {
    font.pointSize: 20
    font.bold: true
    font.family: "Times New Roman"
    textColor: "red"
}
```

#### Default Style

[image: Default TextField style]

#### Custom Style

[image: TextField style in 20pt, bold Times New Roman.]

## Using the `style` member of TextField

If you want to do more in-depth styling of the `TextField` you can attach a `TextFieldStyle` to the `style` member of the `TextField`. The `TextFieldStyle` instance also has a `font` member, though in the IDE it will complain that font has no members if you reference them with dot notation, this may be bug [QTCREATORBUG-11186](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11186). I believe the proper way to assign values is using group notation by referencing the `font` property with inner-items as such:

```
TextField {
    style: TextFieldStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            radius: 10
        }
        font {
            bold: true
            pointSize: 22
        }
        textColor: "white"
    }
}
```

It could be that bug #11186 is a genuine bug, or maybe by design the font property is TextFieldStyle is null; someone with better Qt/QML knowledge could provide a clearer answer as to that part of the question.

This guide on styling may help: http://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling

Comment: I believe that using `style` in Qt6 is now outdated for this and many other QML components as well. Using `font` member mentioned here is the way to go.