# How do I apply the style to a TextField in QML? It seems "style" attribute isn't available

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to apply some styles to a new qt 5.7 application I am working on and the following is not working at all. It gives the error:
qrc:/SignInView.qml:67 Cannot assign to non-existent property "style"
And I can't edit it in design mode for the same reasons.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Page {
    id: page1
    ColumnLayout {
        id: columnLayout1
        height: 100
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top

        Label {
            text: qsTr("Label")
            font.pointSize: 16
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Image {
            id: image1
            width: 200
            height: 200
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent
            source: "qrc:/qtquickplugin/images/template_image.png"

            Button {
                id: button1
                text: qsTr("Button")
                anchors.bottomMargin: 10
                anchors.rightMargin: 10
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.right: parent.right
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: field1
            width: 200
            height: 40
            color: "#ffffff"
            Layout.fillWidth: true



            Label {
                id: label1
                text: qsTr("Full Name")
                anchors.topMargin: 0
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
                anchors.top: parent.top
            }
            TextField {
                style: TextFieldStyle {
                    textColor: "black"
                    background: Rectangle {
                        radius: 2
                        implicitWidth: 100
                        implicitHeight: 24
                        border.color: "#333"
                        border.width: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have being trying to follow this example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-textfieldstyle.html

It fails at the style attribute in the Qt Creator giving the error that style doesn't exist.
I assume it's something with my libraries not loading or maybe the environment I have setup.
I don't have style in buttons or anywhere else either.  I assumed if I had the imports it would work but it's not.

A related issue on SO is here: [QML - How to change TextField font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976887/qml-how-to-change-textfield-font-size)
But here it seems to just work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Qt Quick Controls 2, there is no such property as `TextField::style`. In general, there is no way to use the style objects from Qt Quick Controls 1 with Qt Quick Controls 2. The APIs between the two major versions of Qt Quick Controls are not compatible. See the following documentation pages for more details:

- [Differences between Qt Quick Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html)
- [Styling Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html)
- [Customizing Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html)

A new API-incompatible major version was introduced, because there is basically no way to make the heavily Loader-based architecture of Qt Quick Controls 1 perform reasonably well. Therefore all that dynamic loading of `Component`s was ditched in Qt Quick Controls 2. The delegates that used to be dynamically instantiated from `Component`s provided by a dynamically loaded style object are now part of the control instead, instantiated "in place". In essence:

```
TextField {
    style: TextFieldStyle {
        textColor: "white"
        background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    }
}
```

vs.

```
TextField {
    color: "white"
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
}
```

You can read more about the history [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/category/qt-quick-controls/). In particular, [this post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/31/qt-quick-controls-for-embedded/) highlights the fundamental structural changes in Qt Quick Controls 2.