# TextAreaStyle cannot be assigned to style property

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a problem using the style property to change the text color of a scrollable  TextArea.

I also added the included modules from the .pro file:

```
QT += qml quick core quickcontrols2
```

This is what my .qml file looks like:

```
 import QtQuick 2.7 
 import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
 import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
 import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
 import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
 import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

 ApplicationWindow {
 visible: true
 width: 640
 height: 480
 title: qsTr("Test")

 Page {
     width: parent.width
     height: parent.height
     background: Rectangle {
         color: "#000000"
         width: parent.width
         height: parent.height
     }

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width-50
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        height: 200

        TextArea.flickable: TextArea {
            id: pane1
            text: "This is some text"
            font.bold: false
            font.pointSize: 10
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            clip: true

            style: TextAreaStyle {
                textColor: "#4F4F4F"
            }

            background: Rectangle {
                color: "#FFFFFF"
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
            }
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
    }
 }
 }
```

The Error message I get when running this example:

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>   qrc:/main.qml:38 Cannot assign to non-existent property "style"

I guess I am missing some dependency, but couldn't find anything in the documentation pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: `style` property is not available in controls 2. Styling is inlined in the control. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-textarea). You can also remove `import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4` since it is necessary to styling controls 1.x, which you didn't import.

Comment: Do you wanna answer with that, @BaCaRoZzo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply the style to a TextField in QML? It seems "style" attribute isn't available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052139/how-do-i-apply-the-style-to-a-textfield-in-qml-it-seems-style-attribute-isnt)

Answer (score 3):

*Posting [@BaCaRoZzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538363/bacarozzo)'s comment as a community answer.*

---

`style` property is not available in controls 2. Styling is inlined in the control. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-textarea).

You can also remove import `QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4` since it is necessary to styling controls 1.x, which you didn't import.