# Customize style in QtQuick

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm working with Qt5.7, QtQuick2.7 and QtQuick.Controls 2.0.
I wanted to custom my progressBar but the property "style" is not accepted.

If has already fixed a similar problem with same versions..

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Customizing ProgressBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-progressbar) documentation for an example, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39052406/4666542) for some background information on the subject.

Comment: i didn't find this part of documentation so thank you very much !!